# Movie is not visible on processing

Tags: video, processing, movie

Processing plays the audio of my recorded movie but does not show the movie itself. I tried changing the movie format to wmv but that did not help either.

Here is my code:

```java
import processing.video.*;

Movie vid;

void setup()
{

  size(1600, 900);

  vid= new Movie(this, "Nova.mp4");

  vid.loop();
}
void movieEvent()
{
  vid.read();
    //I tried it without this movie.play() and it did not have any effect. 
  vid.play();
}

void draw()
{
  image(vid, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something looks awry in `movieEvent()`:

1. The [movieEvent()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/movieEvent_.html) function also takes a `Movie` parameter
2. You don't need to call `.play()` for every updated frame

Can you try replacing your `movieEvent()` block of code with this ?

```
void movieEvent(Movie m)
{
  m.read();
}
```